# How to show 1 label box at a time

Tags: forms, label

I sm very new to C#~ as you will soon see.  I am trying to make a for that allows me to enter a gpa and a test score. I have two label boxes, one says you are accepected if you meet the criteria and the other says rejected.  How can I make just one label box show up when it is called?  This is what I have done so far.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const double lowestGPA = 3.0;
        const int lowestTest = 60;
        const int highestTest = 80;
        double gpa;
        double test;
         test = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
        gpa = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

        label3.Visible = true;


        if ((gpa > lowestGPA) && (test > lowestTest))

         label3.Text = "Accepted!";
            else
            label4.Text = "Rejected!";


        if ((gpa < lowestGPA) && (test > highestTest))

            label3.Text = ("Accepected!");
              else
            label4.Text = "Rejected!";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure that I understand but I would do it like this

```
    if (((gpa > lowestGPA) && (test > lowestTest)) || ((gpa < lowestGPA) && (test > highestTest)))

     label3.Text = "Accepted!";
        else
        label3.Text = "Rejected!";
```